# Has anyone ever written a clean MVC based ruby-gnome2 application?

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, gtk, ruby-gnome2

Do you know of any serious and clean, (by clean I mean rails like) mvc based ruby GUI application with GTK.

Actually, if there are any ruby gui applications that are clean and mvc based, I would be delighted, no matter what toolkit.

What I am looking for are basically some good open source apps, where I can look at the code, for inspiration and instruction.

Comment: I have written a couple of ruby-gtk based UIs, which were pretty close to MVC. Do you have a specific question or are you looking for OSS apps so you can look at code?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this gem: [Rugui](http://rugui.org/). From the homepage:

> RuGUI is a framework which aims to help building desktop applications. RuGUI was mostly inspired by the Ruby on Rails  framework, taking most of its features from it.
>
> RuGUI approach is to provide a MVC design for the application, separating business logic from application presentation, making it easy to maintain and evolve the application.

I've been experimenting with it - so no expert on RuGUI - but happy using it. The developers are open for improvement. It supports unit-testing and rspec (with basic support for gui-testing, a few days after asking them).

It only lacks good documentation, but if you know your way around in Gtk it's easy to catch up.

Check out these blogposts:

- [Hello Rugui](http://blog.intelitiva.com/2009/01/hello-rugui/)
- [Getting your feet wet with Rugui](http://blog.intelitiva.com/2009/04/getting-your-feet-wet-with-rugui/)

Comment: It seems to as if there are only two small and simple example applications publicly available to show what rugui does. Not yet convincing.